# Problems with ROLLUP in MySQL 8.0.21

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Using MySQL 8.0.21 on AWS I have a table containing probabilities. Grouping it in 0.1 bands gives the expected results

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(table_s.Prob,1) AS p,COUNT(*) AS c
FROM TableName table_s
GROUP BY TRUNCATE(table_s.Prob,1)

"p" "c"
"0.4"   "85343"
"0.8"   "74197"
"0.1"   "21430"
"0.7"   "107968"
"0.5"   "130740"
"0.9"   "26086"
"0.2"   "35472"
"0.3"   "51087"
"0.6"   "125925"
NULL    "1276971"
"0.0"   "8733"
```

However, if I also try to get the rollup, this messes up the band:

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(table_s.Prob,1) AS p,COUNT(*) AS c,
FROM TableName table_s
GROUP BY TRUNCATE(table_s.Prob,1)
WITH ROLLUP

"p" "c"
NULL    "1276970"
"0"     "8733"
"0."    "21430"
"0."    "35473"
"0."    "51087"
"0."    "85342"
"0."    "130740"
"1"     "125925"
"1"     "107968"
"1"     "74198"
"1"     "26086"
NULL    "1943952"
```

Note the quotes are just from pasting the data from MySQL, Prob is defined as a double (but can have NULLs). Have no idea whatsoever why the p values above have those dots.

Similar behavious applies if rewriting TRUNCATE by using FLOOR or ROUND instead.

Have recently upgraded from MySQL 8.0.17 where I dont think this was an issue and everyhing behaved normally.

The behaviour seems to apply to both 8.0.21 and 8.0.22 as shown on fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df65003f39f8822818e7483f9972fe05

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 ?

Comment: Dont think its a data display issue as I get the same via PHP as well as via SQLyog directly from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been verified as a bug by MySQL. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101684